# Command's CanExecute method is called but not Execute method

Tags: c#, wpf, routed-commands

I've bound a command to a button on a Ribbon control. The CanExecute method on the button gets called as expected but clicking on the button doesn't cause the Execute method to be called. The `CanExecute` sets the `CanExecute` property to `true` - the button in question is enabled and clickable.

Has anyone else seen this behaviour before? If so how do I fix it!

EDIT:

```
CommandBinding commandBinding = new CommandBinding(StaticCommands.ThisCommand, ThisCommandExecutedHandler, ThisCommandCanExecuteHandler);
CommandManager.RegisterClassCommandBinding(this.GetType(), commandBinding);
CommandBindingList.Add(commandBinding);
```

`StaticCommands.ThisCommand` is a `RoutedCommand` with an input gesture of `F5`.

Unfortunately I can't post any xaml because everything is wrapped up in another team's libraries. I am assuming that is correct for now. Also, using the keyboard gesture associated with the command (pressing `F5`) causes the execute method to be called.

There are no exceptions thrown, no messages in the output window, and snoop shows everything bound correctly. I'm really stumped.

Comment: If `CanExecute()` returns false, it **can't** `Execute()`. `CanExecute()` is called, but what does it return when the button is clicked?

Comment: If it's a command binding, clicking wouldn't be available if the CanExecute(object) method returned false.

Comment: @BoltClock could be right.  However, if CanExecute() returns true, we would need to see a bit of code to help diagnose it.

Comment: Please post your XAML and the code that defines the command that is being data-bound in your XAML.

Comment: The `CanExecute` returns true. The button is enabled and clickable.

Comment: To be clear, there is no reason to believe that the command can't `Execute()` if `CanExecute()` returns `false`. `ICommand` is an interface; any implementation can simply ignore the `CanExecute()` method in the `Execute()` implementation and/or always return `true` from its `CanExecute()` implementation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed this by wrapping the `RoutedCommands` in a [`RelayCommand`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/dd419663.aspx#id0090051). I have no idea why that worked, but assuming there's a problem in the other team's assembly.

Answer (score 2):

This usually happens if the parameters dont match in type correctly... are you binding `CommandParameter` of one type and accepting a different type parameter in the Command.Execute() call?

Comment: I'm using the `ExecuteRoutedEventHandler` which just accepts the sender and the event args. Is there a reason that the keyboard gesture would work but not clicking the button?

Comment: Strange! Does the keyboard gesture refers the same `ICommand`? If yes then this indicates that there could be an issue with `CommandBinding` (as `KeyBinding` for same command works). Call `CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();` in `Window_loaded` event and see.